# How to implement Peek and Pop in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, preview, 3dtouch

Many iOS Apps nowadays use `Peek and Pop` to quickly present a Preview of a `DetailView`.
However, all I find on the Internet are Tutorials on how to implement this using `UIKIT`.

**Question:** How do I implement the `iOS Peek & Pop Functionality` using `SwiftUI 2.0` to preview `DetailViews`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `Peek and Pop` features or API in the SwiftUI. It is deprecated in iOS 13.

Instead, you can use the `contextMenu` which you can add to any SwiftUI view.

Below is the example in SwiftUI :

```
HStack {
    Text("Show Context Menu")
    Spacer()
    Text("Press & hold")
}
.contextMenu {
     Button("Button 1 ") {}
     Divider()
     Button("Button 2") {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Does this also present a preview of the DetailView or just the 2 Buttons?

Comment: @christophriepe yes you can use view inside the `contextMenu`

Comment: Shekhar the Context Menu does work. Thank you very much. However, I am not able to present the DetailView on top of the Context Menu. This Code does not work: `.contextMenu {
            DetailView()
             Divider()
             Button("Button 2") {}
        }`